# Flatlist won't fill the entire screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

So i'm new to react native and mobile dev,
i Have a **flatlist**  that i want to stretch on the **entire screen** ***( see the picture i added below )*** but i can't seem to make it happen

here's my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity,Animated, Dimensions } from "react-native";

import { GestureHandler } from "expo";
import { ListItem, List } from "react-native-elements";

import { FlatList, RectButton } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import AppleStyleSwipeableRow from './AppleStyleSwipeableRow';
import GmailStyleSwipeableRow from './GmailStyleSwipeableRow';
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';

const Row = ({ item }) => (
  <RectButton style={styles.rectButton} onPress={() => alert(item.from)}>
    <Text style={styles.fromText}>{item.from}</Text>
    <Text numberOfLines={2} style={styles.messageText}>
      {item.message}
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.dateText}>
       {'❭'}
    </Text>
  </RectButton>
);

const SwipeableRow = ({ item, index }) => {

    return (
      <AppleStyleSwipeableRow >
        <Row item={item} />
      </AppleStyleSwipeableRow>
    );


};

export default class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.separator} />}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <SwipeableRow  
            item={item} index={index} />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => `message ${index}`}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rectButton: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#2C2F33',
  },
  separator: {
    backgroundColor: '#99AAB5',
    height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
  },
  fromText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  messageText: {
    color: '#999',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  dateText: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 20,
    top: 10,
    color: 'pink', //'#7289DA',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

const DATA = [
  {
    from: "D'Artagnan",
    when: '3:11 PM',
    message:
      'Unus pro omnibus, omnes pro uno. Nunc scelerisque, massa non lacinia porta, quam odio dapibus enim, nec tincidunt dolor leo non neque',
  },
  {
    from: 'Aramis',
    when: '11:46 AM',
    message:
      'Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus hendrerit ligula dignissim maximus aliquet. Integer tincidunt, tortor at finibus molestie, ex tellus laoreet libero, lobortis consectetur nisl diam viverra justo.',
  },
  {
    from: 'Athos',
    when: '6:06 AM',
    message:
      'Sed non arcu ullamcorper, eleifend velit eu, tristique metus. Duis id sapien eu orci varius malesuada et ac ipsum. Ut a magna vel urna tristique sagittis et dapibus augue. Vivamus non mauris a turpis auctor sagittis vitae vel ex. Curabitur accumsan quis mauris quis venenatis.',
  }/*,
  {
    from: 'Porthos',
    when: 'Yesterday',
    message:
      'Vivamus id condimentum lorem. Duis semper euismod luctus. Morbi maximus urna ut mi tempus fermentum. Nam eget dui sed ligula rutrum venenatis.',
  },
  {
    from: 'Domestos',
    when: '2 days ago',
    message:
      'Aliquam imperdiet dolor eget aliquet feugiat. Fusce tincidunt mi diam. Pellentesque cursus semper sem. Aliquam ut ullamcorper massa, sed tincidunt eros.',
  },
  {
    from: 'Cardinal Richelieu',
    when: '2 days ago',
    message:
      'Pellentesque id quam ac tortor pellentesque tempor tristique ut nunc. Pellentesque posuere ut massa eget imperdiet. Ut at nisi magna. Ut volutpat tellus ut est viverra, eu egestas ex tincidunt. Cras tellus tellus, fringilla eget massa in, ultricies maximus eros.',
  },
  {
    from: "D'Artagnan",
    when: 'Week ago',
    message:
      'Aliquam non aliquet mi. Proin feugiat nisl maximus arcu imperdiet euismod nec at purus. Vestibulum sed dui eget mauris consequat dignissim.',
  },
  {
    from: 'Cardinal Richelieu',
    when: '2 weeks ago',
    message:
      'Vestibulum ac nisi non augue viverra ullamcorper quis vitae mi. Donec vitae risus aliquam, posuere urna fermentum, fermentum risus. ',
  },*/
];
```

here's a picture

[image]

basically i want the **flatlist** the fill that **empty white space** i honestly don't know where the problem is coming from since i tried adding the `flex: 1`

Comment: Add `flexGrow: 1` in your Flatlist style.

Comment: @KishanBharda i added  `style ={{flexGrow : 1}}` and nothing happens !!

Comment: I means both `style={{flex: 1, flexGrow: 1}}`

Comment: @KishanBharda same, nothing,  i can do a work-around and change the `paddingVertical: '25%' ` in my `rectButton: {} ` style definition, but i want the flat list to be equally spreaded across all screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tbh i don't know why the other options didn't work but i found a way around as i mentioned; 
i changed the `paddingVertical:10` to become `paddingVertical: '25%'` in the `rectButton{}` style

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity,Animated, Dimensions } from "react-native";

import { GestureHandler } from "expo";
import { ListItem, List } from "react-native-elements";

import { FlatList, RectButton } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import AppleStyleSwipeableRow from './AppleStyleSwipeableRow';
import GmailStyleSwipeableRow from './GmailStyleSwipeableRow';
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';

const Row = ({ item }) => (
  <RectButton style={styles.rectButton} onPress={() => alert(item.from)}>
    <Text style={styles.fromText}>{item.from}</Text>
    <Text numberOfLines={2} style={styles.messageText}>
      {item.message}
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.dateText}>
       {'❭'}
    </Text>
  </RectButton>
);

const SwipeableRow = ({ item, index }) => {

    return (
      <AppleStyleSwipeableRow >
        <Row item={item} />
      </AppleStyleSwipeableRow>
    );


};

export default class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
      <FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
        data={DATA}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.separator} />}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <SwipeableRow  
            item={item} index={index} />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => `message ${index}`}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rectButton: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#2C2F33',
  },
  separator: {
    backgroundColor: '#99AAB5',
    height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
  },
  fromText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  messageText: {
    color: '#999',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  dateText: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 20,
    top: 10,
    color: 'pink', //'#7289DA',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

const DATA = [
  {
    from: "D'Artagnan",
    when: '3:11 PM',
    message:
      'Unus pro omnibus, omnes pro uno. Nunc scelerisque, massa non lacinia porta, quam odio dapibus enim, nec tincidunt dolor leo non neque',
  },
  {
    from: 'Aramis',
    when: '11:46 AM',
    message:
      'Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus hendrerit ligula dignissim maximus aliquet. Integer tincidunt, tortor at finibus molestie, ex tellus laoreet libero, lobortis consectetur nisl diam viverra justo.',
  },
  {
    from: 'Athos',
    when: '6:06 AM',
    message:
      'Sed non arcu ullamcorper, eleifend velit eu, tristique metus. Duis id sapien eu orci varius malesuada et ac ipsum. Ut a magna vel urna tristique sagittis et dapibus augue. Vivamus non mauris a turpis auctor sagittis vitae vel ex. Curabitur accumsan quis mauris quis venenatis.',
  }/*,
  {
    from: 'Porthos',
    when: 'Yesterday',
    message:
      'Vivamus id condimentum lorem. Duis semper euismod luctus. Morbi maximus urna ut mi tempus fermentum. Nam eget dui sed ligula rutrum venenatis.',
  },
  {
    from: 'Domestos',
    when: '2 days ago',
    message:
      'Aliquam imperdiet dolor eget aliquet feugiat. Fusce tincidunt mi diam. Pellentesque cursus semper sem. Aliquam ut ullamcorper massa, sed tincidunt eros.',
  },
  {
    from: 'Cardinal Richelieu',
    when: '2 days ago',
    message:
      'Pellentesque id quam ac tortor pellentesque tempor tristique ut nunc. Pellentesque posuere ut massa eget imperdiet. Ut at nisi magna. Ut volutpat tellus ut est viverra, eu egestas ex tincidunt. Cras tellus tellus, fringilla eget massa in, ultricies maximus eros.',
  },
  {
    from: "D'Artagnan",
    when: 'Week ago',
    message:
      'Aliquam non aliquet mi. Proin feugiat nisl maximus arcu imperdiet euismod nec at purus. Vestibulum sed dui eget mauris consequat dignissim.',
  },
  {
    from: 'Cardinal Richelieu',
    when: '2 weeks ago',
    message:
      'Vestibulum ac nisi non augue viverra ullamcorper quis vitae mi. Donec vitae risus aliquam, posuere urna fermentum, fermentum risus. ',
  },*/
];
```

Comment: this didn't solve it, check my answer below, but thanks for the contribution anyways <3